# Show $\ln(x^2+t^2)$ in $\mathcal{L}^1$

Tags: real-analysis, integration

Let $h:(0,8)\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$, $h(t)=\int_{[0,1]}\ln(x^2+t^2)\ d\lambda(x)$, $t\in(0,\infty)$. I'm trying to show that $h$ is differentiable, which means I first have to check that the integral is well-defined.

I need to show that $\ln(x^2+t^2)$ is in $\mathcal{L}^1$, meaning it is measurable (which it is because the term is continuous for $t\in(0,\infty$)), and have a finite integral. However I'm stuck with this part. I've tried looking at some inequalities, but it doesn't get me anywhere. Any hints?

Comment: Hint: try to show $\int_0^1|\ln(x^2+t^2)|d\lambda(x)<\infty$.

Comment: Hint: First note, that for big $t$ we have no problem. For $t \geq \epsilon > 0$ we have $x^2 + t^2 \geq t^2 \geq \epsilon^2$. Thus $|ln(x^2 + t^2)|\leq |ln(\epsilon^2)|$ for $t$ small enough.

Comment: @OlesWohnzimmer, use integration by parts.

Comment: @OlesWohnzimmer Why does $x^2+t^2\geq \epsilon^2$ imply $|ln(x^2+t^2)|\leq |ln(\epsilon^2)|$ ?

Comment: what is $\mathrm{d}\lambda(x)$? Is it different than $\mathrm{d}x$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note $\ln x>0$ if $x\ge1$ and $\ln x<0$ if $0<x<1$. Thus if $t\ge 1$, then
$$ \int_0^1|\ln(x^2+t^2)|d\lambda(x)\le\ln(1+t^2)<\infty. $$
If $0<t<1$, then
\begin{eqnarray}
\int_0^1|\ln(x^2+t^2)|d\lambda(x)&=&\int_0^{\sqrt{1-t^2}}|\ln(x^2+t^2)|d\lambda(x)+\int^1_{\sqrt{1-t^2}}|\ln(x^2+t^2)|d\lambda(x)\\
&=&\int_0^{\sqrt{1-t^2}}\ln\frac{1}{x^2+t^2}d\lambda(x)+\int^1_{\sqrt{1-t^2}}\ln(x^2+t^2)d\lambda(x)\\
&\le&\int_0^{\sqrt{1-t^2}}\ln\frac{1}{x^2}d\lambda(x)+\int^1_{\sqrt{1-t^2}}\ln(1+t^2)d\lambda(x)\\
&\le&-2\int_0^{1}\ln xd\lambda(x)+\ln(1+t^2)\\
&=&2+\ln(1+t^2)<\infty.
\end{eqnarray}
Thus for $\forall t\in(0,\infty)$, $\int_0^1|\ln(x^2+t^2)|d\lambda(x)<\infty$ and hence $\ln(x^2+t^2)$ is in $L^1$.

Comment: $$ \begin{align} \int_0^1\log\left(x^2+t^2\right)\,\mathrm{d}x &=2\log(t)+\int_0^1\log\left(1+\frac{x^2}{t^2}\right)\,\mathrm{d}x\\ &\ge2\log(t) \end{align} $$

Comment: @robjohn, tut it does not mean $\int_0^1|\log(x^2+t^2)|dx\ge2|\log(t)|$.

Comment: If $t\ge1$, how is that any different? Your first inequality is the opposite.

Comment: @robjohn, I made a mistake in the first inequality. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Let $x \in [0,1], t>0$.

Then $\ln(x)$ is an increasing function, so

$$\ln(t^2) \leq \ln(x^2 + t^2) \leq \ln(1+t^2)$$

So $|\ln(x^2+t^2)|$ is bounded over $x\in[0,1]$ for any $t>0$. Thus the integral is finite.